# NSUrlsession RequestCachePolicy returning 304 instead of 200

Tags: ios, urlsession

I am using `URLSession` with `useProtocolCachePolicy`. I am getting 304 instead of 200.

I searched everywhere `sessionConfig.requestCachePolicy = .useProtocolCachePolicy` returns 200 instead of 304, but in my case it is opposite. Can anyone please tell me the reason?

```
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.setValue("Etag", forHTTPHeaderField: "If-None-Match")

let sessionConfig  = URLSessionConfiguration.default
sessionConfig.requestCachePolicy = .useProtocolCachePolicy
let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
   print(httpResponse.statusCode) //First time 200, second time onward 304
}.resume()
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set your cache policy to reloadIgnoringCacheData.

```
request.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringCacheData
```

Status code 304 means as below

- If the client has performed a conditional GET request and access is
  allowed, but the document has not been modified, the server SHOULD
  respond with this status code. The 304 response MUST NOT contain a
  message-body, and thus is always terminated by the first empty line
  after the header fields. Check for the HTTPS status code here.

Here is the list of codes

[HTTPS Status Codes](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)